# How to Instantiate Classes while passing randomized values from 1 to 6 but each randomized value is passed exactly twice

Tags: java, oop

I want to create 12 instantiations of a class and pass a random value as its parameter. The random values should only range from 1 to 6 BUT I need each value from the range to be distributed twice among the 12 instances of the class.

The constructor of the Class is as follows:

```
Die(int numSide){
    this.numside = numSide;
}
```

Basically, I want to create 12 instances of dice with 2 of each side, sort of, as a result of a tossing.

Comment: *The random values should only range from 1 to 6* Then the ctor you showed is redundant and it can be a regular die with an empty ctor. You want 12 or 12 *pairs*? Either way you can create them in a loop and add to an array or collections

Comment: @g00se I actually omitted 2 other parameters for clarity. I need the constructors for this code.

Comment: Repetitions or not? i.e. would you be OK with say 2 x four sides *twice over*?

Comment: Repetitions, yes. Two for every side. So I would have six pair instances of every side, but each instances should also be unique. I'm thinking of putting it in an ArrayList but I'm still not entirely sure what would work best.

Comment: This Question is quite confusing. Rewrite for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the numbers 1 to 6, twice to an ArrayList. Now pick a random index from that last and pass that to your Die constructor. Remove that index from the pool so it doesn't get used again.

Something like:

```
  public static void main( String [] args) {   
    List<Die> dice = new ArrayList<Die>();
    List<Integer> pool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=1; i<=2; i++) {
      for(int num=1; num<=6; num++) {
        pool.add(num);
      }
    }

    while (pool.size() > 0) {
      int index = (int)(Math.random() * pool.size());
      dice.add(new Die(pool.get(index)));
      pool.remove(index);
    }

    for(Die d : dice) {
      System.out.println(d.numside);
    }
  }
```

My output:

```
2
3
3
1
4
6
5
6
4
5
2
1
```

An alternative approach would be to add the Die instances directly to the Dice arraylist from the nested for loops, then simply pull a random instance from that list and remove it. Same concept as the pool, just depends on whether you need to use and/or keep that random order of Die instances for something else.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly and exactly how I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is confused. So I will focus on:

> pass a random value
>
> …
>
> range from 1 to 6 BUT I need each value from the range to be distributed twice

## `IntStream`

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to generate numbers.

Put together two streams of 1-6 inclusive. Generate an array from their output. Shuffle that array. Loop that array to get each `int` value.

```java
int[] oneThruSixTwice = 
    IntStream.concat
    (
        IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , 6 ) ,
        IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , 6 )
    )
    .toArray() ;
Collections.shuffle( oneThruSixTwice ) ;
for( int x : oneThruSixTwice )
{
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Basil Bourque (though note you can't shuffle an array with `Collections`) you could do:

```
    List<Die> dice = IntStream.concat(
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 6),
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 6))
                .mapToObj(i -> new Die(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(dice);
    dice.stream()
        .forEach(
            die -> System.out.printf("Die with %d side(s) rolled %d%n", die.getNumSides(), die.roll()));
```

On the last run, this gave me:

```
Die with 5 side(s) rolled 4
Die with 4 side(s) rolled 1
Die with 6 side(s) rolled 2
Die with 4 side(s) rolled 3
Die with 1 side(s) rolled 1
Die with 3 side(s) rolled 2
Die with 5 side(s) rolled 5
Die with 1 side(s) rolled 1
Die with 3 side(s) rolled 3
Die with 2 side(s) rolled 2
Die with 2 side(s) rolled 1
Die with 6 side(s) rolled 1
```